# Serverless deploy doesn't integrate AWS Lambda with SQS event

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

I am trying to create an AWS SQS event associated with an AWS Lambda function called 'sendExportJob' using Serverless framework but after the deploy I can not see in the AWS console the SQS trigger. Obviously, I can add this event manually through the console and it works as expected.

Here is the Lambda function configuration in the serverless.yml:

```
sendExportJob:
  handler: src/sendExportJob.handler
  role: sendExportJobIAM
  memorySize: ${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.memorySize}
  timeout: ${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.timeout} 
  environment:
    lambdaName: ${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.name}
    pendingqueueUrl: https://sqs.${self:custom.config.region}.amazonaws.com/${self:custom.config.account-id}/${self:custom.config.sqs-pending-exports-queue-name}
    region: ${self:custom.config.region} 
  events:
    - schedule: rate(${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.schedule-rate-minutes} minutes)
    - pendingsqs:
      arn:  arn:aws:sqs:${self:custom.config.region}:${self:custom.config.account-id}:${self:custom.config.sqs-pending-exports-queue-name}
      batchSize: 1
```

Here is the IAM configuration for this particular function:

```
 sendExportJobIAM:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: sendExportJobRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: sendExportJobIAMAll
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility
                  - sqs:ChangeMessageVisibilityBatch
                  - sqs:DeleteMessage
                  - sqs:DeleteMessageBatch
                  - sqs:GetQueueAttributes
                  - sqs:ReceiveMessage
                Resource:   arn:aws:sqs:${self:custom.config.region}:${self:custom.config.account-id}:${self:custom.config.sqs-pending-exports-queue-name}
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - lambda:InvokeFunction
                Resource: '*'
```

I am using the latest version of the Serverless framework and I have checked the indentation in the configuration file.

The SQS resource has been deployed previously so it already exists before adding it as an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `sqs` attribute under your `events` section. I am not really sure what you meant with `pendingsqs` as that is not a valid Serverless Framework's keyword

```
sendExportJob:
  handler: src/sendExportJob.handler
  role: sendExportJobIAM
  memorySize: ${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.memorySize}
  timeout: ${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.timeout} 
  environment:
    lambdaName: ${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.name}
    pendingqueueUrl: https://sqs.${self:custom.config.region}.amazonaws.com/${self:custom.config.account-id}/${self:custom.config.sqs-pending-exports-queue-name}
    region: ${self:custom.config.region} 
  events:
    - schedule: rate(${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.schedule-rate-minutes} minutes)
    - sqs: arn:aws:sqs:${self:custom.config.region}:${self:custom.config.account-id}:${self:custom.config.sqs-pending-exports-queue-name}
```

If you want to configure the batch size, like you did above, just put it under the `sqs` item in the `events` list, like so:

```
sendExportJob:
      handler: src/sendExportJob.handler
      role: sendExportJobIAM
      memorySize: ${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.memorySize}
      timeout: ${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.timeout} 
      environment:
        lambdaName: ${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.name}
        pendingqueueUrl: https://sqs.${self:custom.config.region}.amazonaws.com/${self:custom.config.account-id}/${self:custom.config.sqs-pending-exports-queue-name}
        region: ${self:custom.config.region} 
      events:
        - schedule: rate(${self:custom.config.send-exportjob-lambda-settings.schedule-rate-minutes} minutes)
        - sqs: 
            arn: aws:sqs:${self:custom.config.region}:${self:custom.config.account-id}:${self:custom.config.sqs-pending-exports-queue-name}
            batchSize: 1
```

This is all documented [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sqs/)